# My External USB Hard Drive won't show up

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

My External USB Hard Drive don't show up.

[image]

I checked in Computer Management, Disk Management and Device Management, the partition of my Hard Disk exists

[image]

I was trying to install a linux distribution on my laptop, I'am worrying that I changed some things while choosing partition for install unconsciently (May be the file system type became ext4 or something ..).
How can solve this ! and please don't tell me that I should format my disk all my data are there !! Regards

Comment: You will need to translate the text in the screenshot.  Be sure you indicate what type of file system you choose on the partition in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ! Thanks God I resolved my problem and I restore all my data!
Here is the steps:

1- Download & Install Partition Guru link :http://www.partitionguru.com/download.php

2- Partition Guru will show all the hard disk available .

3-You select your hard drive and then click on Tools> Search Lost Partition (Partition Recovery)

4-Then you click on save All button.

A window will ask you to choose between MBR or GUI.

choose MBR and click save.
And magically every things is done !
You can also recreate you table allocation:Tools> create MBR table allocation and after that you save .